# UITableview Selected row's Screenshot

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my App I use `UITableview` with dynamic data from Web service result.

Now When I `select one` row at a time i need `screenshot` of that row.

For Ex: In Tableview with 10 rows. & Each Row contain Profile image,First Name & Last name.

So when  I click on second Row at time take screenshot of only second row .

Comment: Use CGGraphics to draw the layout of that row and use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.contentView.frame.size);

    [cell.contentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

:)

Comment: Yes it's Work..Thanks